# How to debug in a mean.io app?

Tags: javascript, mean.io

Whenever I run my mean.io app, I can see all my functions in the aggregated.js. Is there a way to do plain and simple browser debbuging?

This question is for front-end debugging... but it would be great to know how to do backend debugging also.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Javascript console (F12) and [`console.*`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) methods?

Comment: yes of course. When i open my console is where I see that all my functions are aggregated to the aggregated.js file. It's minified, so really hard to debug anything... The question is, how to use the javascript console to debug mean.io apps

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but in Chrome on the bottom, left of the Sources page pane, there's a `{}` button (it doesn't really look like a button...). Click that and the code in the pane will be formatted for readability. I'm not familiar specifically with mean.io, so I'll let others take it from here.

Comment: wow, I never would imagine that a button. Thanks, no I can at least read my code :)

Comment: If mean.io has a compiler, there's probably a debug or other flag to skip the minification step.

Comment: It uses grunt for launching the app ( you just do a "$ grunt" on the app folder). But I found commands to minify with grunt, not to "not minify" with grunt :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836090/how-to-stop-minification-of-js-files-in-grunt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in config\env\all.js, add a switch: debug: true

Comment: Please, provide some references to it. For which object debug switch should be set? I know only about **db** debug option. But this question is about front-end debugging.

Comment: follow the line: 
templateEngine: 'swig',

add new line:
debug: true,

Comment: Thanks! after setting it, the aggregated.js (which has all the front-end code) was readable and debugable

Comment: @yannis there is a little change see below answer

Answer (score 2):

Updated way is changed a little bit

in `config\env\all.js, add a switch: debug: 'true'`

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For those who 'debug: true' doesn't work... try this.

1. Open 'aggregation.js' located in node_modules/meanio/lib
2. At around line 125, you'll find the following hunk of code.  Make the following change:

   aggregated[group][ext].weights[filename] = {
   weight: weight,
   //data: !this.debug ? ugly.code : code  //  <---------- comment this out
   data: code   //   <----------------- add this
   }

See attached image for more detail.

[image: Purty picture of what to do]